# Filtering out date array in Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, filter

`dates`, and `values` are corelated. I am trying to code a function where it filters out all the values in the `values` array after the `given_date`. Since the `given_date` is `'2017-09-15 11:40:30'`, The first two indexes in dates `'2017-09-15 07:11:00' ,'2017-09-15 11:25:30'` comes before the `given_date` so the first tow indexes in `values` is filtered out. Resulting in the Expected Output. How would I be able to do that?

```
given_date= '2017-09-15 11:40:30'
dates= np.array(['2017-09-15 07:11:00' ,'2017-09-15 11:25:30', '2017-09-15 12:11:10', '2021-04-07 22:43:12', '2021-04-08 00:49:18'])
values= np.array([10,30,44,55,60])
```

Expected Output:

```
[44,55,60]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These `dates` are actually *strings*, so you should [treat them as dates](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html):

```
import numpy as np

given_date = np.datetime64('2017-09-15 11:40:30')
dates = np.array([
    '2017-09-15 07:11:00' ,'2017-09-15 11:25:30', '2017-09-15 12:11:10', '2021-04-07 22:43:12', '2021-04-08 00:49:18'
], np.datetime64)
values = np.array([10,30,44,55,60])

# Use comparison operators like you would with numbers
print(values[dates > given_date])
```

Comment: Hey I have another question that is related to this question could u take a look at it possibly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67813476/using-arithmetics-with-datetime-and-arrays-numpy-python